# jQuery: Uncheck other checkbox on one checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am having total 6 checkbox ( may be add more in future ) and I want to allow only select one so when user checked any of them other should unchecked.

I tried with this code and works fine if I defined ID but now just wonder how to make it vice versa in efficient way so in future if I add more than it wont be a problem

```
$('#type1').click(function() {
     $('#type2').not('#type1').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

FYI, checkboxs are not sibling and are in different `<td>`

Comment: If you always want one checkbox checked, why don't you use radio buttons instead ?

Comment: Please post your html code

Comment: Set a class for them.

Comment: @AGuif, I can't use radio button due to some restriction. I have only option to use checkbox.

Comment: You are describing a radio input.

Comment: @pixelngrain <<I can't use radio button due to some restriction>> Which kind of restriction doesn't let you use a radio button?

Comment: Nvm. Some restriction.

Comment: he didn't say he always wanted one checked, he wants one checked at most, which is different

Comment: It is wholly possible, and much more sensible, to use radio buttons that you can check and uncheck to guarantee that at most one input is selected, and to style them to look like checkboxes. Was the client going to run a unit test and decline to pay if they find any input element without `type="checkbox"`? Come now...

Comment: The possible reason: with checkboxes you can reset all values in the group on second click, which is abnormal behaviour for radio-buttons

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Bind a `change` handler, then just uncheck all of the checkboxes, apart from the one checked:

```
$('input.example').on('change', function() {
    $('input.example').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MQM8k/)

Comment: This code does not removes the previously selected checked radio button in my case.. Please change the accepted answer to the one below with 11 upvotes, (if you can).. Cheers..

Comment: @vidal this answer is correct. Are you using a really old version of jQuery?

Comment: How would this look in pure js?

Answer (score 16):

you could use class for all your checkboxes, and do:

```
$(".check_class").click(function() {
  $(".check_class").attr("checked", false); //uncheck all checkboxes
  $(this).attr("checked", true);  //check the clicked one
});
```

Comment: Sudhir, bahot shukriya but when its checked second checkbox it is not removing and checked forever

Comment: .prop() is preferred method here. BTW, you could exclude 'this' from first set of matched elements

Comment: @pixelngrain see billyonecan's jsfiddle, really better and you should use onchange event not onclick, especially for older browsers

Comment: +1 @billyonecan your code is amazing. It's works exactly what I want. and keep checkbox behavior as well.

Comment: Post it as an answer as this way it's easier for JS newbies to remember and use.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
 $(function() { 
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
  });
});
```

Comment: `$('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);` is enough

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("[id*='type']").click(
function () {
var isCheckboxChecked = this.checked;
$("[id*='type']").attr('checked', false);
this.checked = isCheckboxChecked;
});
```

To make it even more generic you can also find checkboxes by the common class implemented on them.

Modified...

Comment: Shukriya Abhishek, code works fine just one issue when I clicked on checked checkbox it is removing and checked another checkbox as well.. any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.cw2').change(function () {
    if ($('input.cw2').filter(':checked').length >= 1) {
        $('input.cw2').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    } 
});


$('td, input').prop(function (){
    $(this).css({ 'background-color': '#DFD8D1' });
    $(this).addClass('changed');
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It helps if you explain why your answer works and what needed to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add an answer if the checkboxes are being generated in a loop. For example if your structure is like this (Assuming you are using server side constructs on your `View`, like a `foreach` loop):

```
<li id="checkboxlist" class="list-group-item card">
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">Checkbox 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">Checkbox 2</label>
  </div>
</li>

<li id="checkboxlist" class="list-group-item card">
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">Checkbox 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">Checkbox 2</label>
  </div>
</li>
```

Corresponding `Jquery`:

```
$(".list-group-item").each(function (i, li) {
  var currentli = $(li);
  $(currentli).find("#checkbox1").on('change', function () {
       $(currentli).find("#checkbox2").not(this).prop('checked',false);
  });

  $(currentli).find("#checkbox2").on('change', function () {
       $(currentli).find("#checkbox1").not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

Working DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/gr67qk20/

Answer (score 0):

I think the prop method is more convenient when it comes to boolean attribute.
http://api.jquery.com/prop/